# ACT English Question

Tags: relative-pronouns, who-whom

I was perusing through past ACT English questions, and I came across the question:

> "while pretending to be a person _____  in a different country and century"

The possible answers were:

- A: whom had lived
- B: who were to live
- C: whom lived
- D: who lived

The correct answer was D, but I am having trouble understanding why it is "D." My thought is that it would have to be whom, as the subject, person, was the object of the verb "be." Thus, "D" seemed impossible from my point of view. Could anyone share some insight into why my path of thinking was incorrect?

Comment: No, you were perusing past ACT English questions.....

Comment: Please see the answers at ["a patient who is" or "a patient whom is"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14761/a-patient-who-is-or-a-patient-whom-is) and, if you dare, the answers to the question that that question is said to duplicate—[What's the rule for using "who" and "whom" correctly?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly) If none of those answers clarify your "who/whom" question, we may not be able to explain it satisfactorily.

Comment: There are two errors here. The verb "be" doesn't take an object; it takes a complement. In colloquial speech, the complement of "be" is normally in the accusative (as in "It's me") but in very formal speech the rule used to be that the complement should match the case of the subject ("It is I"). Since "whom" only occurs in formal speech, it's never correct to use "whom" as the complement of the verb "to be". (For example, you should say "Who is it?"; *"Whom is it" is wrong.)

Comment: The other error is that the case of "who(m)" is determined by its role in the embedded clause (the clause that comes after it, in this case), not by its role in the main clause. In this case, its role in the embedded clause is as the *subject* of the verb "lived".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the whole sentence takes the following form:

**Joe was a local resident while pretending to be a person who lived in a different time and place.**

The word "who" in this sentence functions as a relative pronoun which begins a relative clause. The whole relative clause is: "who lived in a different time and place."

The word "person" is the antecedent of the relative clause (as in "person who lived...").

In the wikipedia article on such clauses, you find the following rule: 
**"whom is used only when its antecedent is the object of the relative clause, but not when its antecedent is the subject of a sentence or clause..."**

The question now is: How does the antecedent function in relationship to the relative clause? In this case "person" is the subject of the clause, not the object of the clause.

Consider now a relative clause which would use "whom:"

Joe was a hated resident while pretending to be a person **whom** we all loved.

In this case, person is the antecedent, but it functions as the object of the clause.

- Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses

Comment: What does it even mean for the grammar of a relative clause to "match" its antecedent? Don't we know that *who* is the right pronoun in the clause "who lived in a different time and place" even when we don't know the antecedent for *who*?

Comment: Good question. I added another sentence to clarify what I meant.

Comment: This is a very confusing explanation, and I think it might be wrong (although I can't say since I don't really understand it).

Comment: There's a simple test for this which doesn't take the antecedent into account at all.  The important part is the relative clause: "*who lived in a different time and place.*" We would say *"he lived in a different time and place,"* not *"him lived in a different time and place."* Now, let's see how this test works with *whom*: For *"whom I never met"*, you would say "*I never met him*", not *"I never met he"*. The test: replace *who(m)* with *he/him*. You might have to reorder the clause to do this.  If you would use *he*, use *who*. If you would use *him*, use *whom*.

Comment: @DonJewett It's clear now, and clearly wrong. Consider *Praise him, Goddess, who came to Troy from Aegina*. The antecedent of *who* is *him*. The latter is in the objective case (as the direct object of *praise*), but the pronoun is in the subjective case (as the subject of the relative clause).  I can do vice versa if you wish. This is a basic misunderstanding of the recursive nature of English grammar. In general, subordinate clauses have the same grammar as the clauses they're subordinate to. Please consider a revision of your answer.

Comment: " the grammar of the relative clause will always match its antecedent" is the most confusing and apparently wrong part of the answer. As deadrat mentions in the above comment, it's not true if by "grammar" you mean "the surface case". It's true if you mean something like "the relative pronoun is always co-referential with the antecedent, and takes the case that the antecedent would take if the antecedent was put into a separate independent clause (e.g. "who" in "the person who lived" should be in the same case as "the person" would be in "the person lived").

Comment: Excellent points. Please see my corrections. I believe the result is easier to follow and correct. I do disagree about the example "praise him who came to Troy." The word "him" is in the objective case because he's the direct object of praise. However, he is the subject of the relative clause. He is not the direct object of the verb come, he is the one who came.

Comment: The op's understandable confusion is due to the fact that the person is an object -- not only of "to be" but of "pretending." The antecedent of the relative clause is the important factor. How does the antecedent function in the relative clause? Subject or object? How it functions in the rest of the sentence is irrelevant.

Comment: @PeterShor -- The he/him rule is a trap in this case. See deadrat's example of "Goddess, praise him who came to Troy..." (edited for clarity) and my response. In this case "him" is correct, but so is "who."